# Is there a way to send update to only the latest build with EAS?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

In my latest build for iOS, there are a few bugs that I need to fix for production. Because of the nature of these bugs, I cannot reproduce them using Expo Go, meaning that the only way to fix them is to release an OTA update. However, if I release an OTA update, then it will be sent to all users of my app, which is not what I want. My question is whether or not I can send an OTA update to only my device. Thanks in advance.